# Unable to Convert All Items in SQLAlchemy Object to Key-Value in Dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to convert each row in a SQLAlchemy results object into a dictionary where each column header is a key. Not all of the columns in my query are returned in the dictionary, though. None of the columns from the "Project" table are visible.

Is there an additional step needed in my for loop to unpack these columns and their values?

```
projects_for_template = (
      db.session.query(Project, func.count(Entry.id).label('entry_count'))
      .join(Entry, Project.name == Entry.project)
      .group_by(Project)
)

projects_for_template_list = []

for row in projects_for_template.all():
        row_dict = row._asdict()
        projects_for_template_list.append(row_dict)

print (projects_for_template_list)

[{'entry_count': 45L, 'Project': <Project 1>}, {'entry_count': 3L, 'Project': <Project 2>}, {'entry_count': 62L, 'Project': <Project 3>}]
```

I would have expected to see something like this...

```
[{'entry_count': 45L, 'project_id': 123, 'client_name': XYZcorp, 'analyst_name': Bob}, {'entry_count': 3L, 'project_id': 456, 'client_name': Acme_Inc, 'analyst_name': Jane}, {'entry_count': 62L, 'project_id': 789, 'client_name': Innotek, 'analyst_name': Michael}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are requesting for entire `Project` object rather than the individual fields of `Project`

```
projects_for_template = (
      db.session.query(Project.id,Project.client_name,func.count(Entry.id).label('entry_count'))
      .join(Entry, Project.name == Entry.project)
      .group_by(Project.id,Project.client_name) # add all the fields here
)
```

OR

You can also iterate over the result set and convert the Project object to fetch the key values with making changes to the sql